# How to add serial number to a range query in SQL?

Tags: sql, db2

I am selecting records within different ranges with a select statement like

```
select t.range as profit_range, count(*) as number_ of_occurences   from (
  select case 
    when t.range between  100000000 and  200000000 then '100 million - 200 million'
    when t.range between  200000000 and  300000000 then '200 million - 300 million'
    .
    .
    .
    when t.range between  1000000000 and  2000000000 then '1000 million - 2000 million'
    else 'Greater then 2000 milions' end as range
  from tbl_profit) t
group by profit_range
```

This works but the order of the resulting rows is not correct

```
 Profit_Range                       No_of_occurences    
 100 million  - 200 million           4
 1000 million - 2000 million          1
 200 million  - 300 million           4
```

How do I order the results to appear in the right order?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry that was not the actual query of my system, just a sample. I have updated the same in my original post.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t.range as [profit range], count(*) as [number of occurences]
from (
  select case 
    when profit between  100000000 and  200000000 then '100 million - 200 million'
    when profit between  200000000 and  300000000 then '200 million - 300 million'
    .
    .
    .
    when profit between  1000000000 and  2000000000 then '1000 million - 2000 million'
    else 'Greater then 2000 milions' end as range
    from tbl_profit) t
group by t.range
Order by SUBSTR(t.range,1,LOCATE(‘million’,t.range)-1)
```

You can extract starting number from range using `SUBSTR()` and `LOCATE` functions and order result according to extracted number

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you tell me exactly how the expression SUBSTR(t.range,1,LOCATE(‘million’,t.range)-1) evaluates logically?

Comment: locate() function finds starting position of first occurrence of 'million' . Substr() extracts substring starting from position 1 i.e. start uptill position found earlier which gives number at strat of range.

Comment: @m hasan Thanks for your reply. Onething more, why are you subtracting 1 from locate? Also I got this to work by casting the substring as int. If you can update, I will mark this as answer. Thanks for your wonderful solution!